# Which simple python based WSGI compatible jsonrpc library to use in server side for 'pyjamas'?

Tags: python, web-applications, json-rpc, pyjamas

Recently, I came across [pyjamas](http://pyjs.org) framework. It encourages radically different web application development approach by seperating the whole 'view' component of 'MVC' into some html + javascript (generated with compiled python), instead of using traditional templating. This client side 'view' is supposed to communicate with the server through Asynchronous HTTP Requests, and the framework recommends using 'jsonrpc' as communication protocol.

In their documentation, they used a django based jsonrpc component. But I am mostly used to simple and stupid solutions like [bottle framework](http://bottlepy.org). As far as I understand, I don't even need all the components of such microframeworks. A WSGI compatible server, some routing + session middleware and a request handler which understands in terms of jsonrpc will do just fine. I am looking for an easy to use light weight solution for the last part - readily available jsonrpc-aware request handler that plugs nicely in WSGI environment. Is their any?

Please pardon and correct my misuse/misunderstanding of terms, if any.

Answer (score 1):

You might have chosen some library by now. But anyways.

I use flask and and [jsonrpc2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonrpc2). Here is some psudo code. My code is very similar.

```
import jsonrpc2

mapper = jsonrpc2.JsonRpc()
mapper['echo'] = str

@app.route('/rpc', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def rpc():
    #req {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": methodname, "params": params, "id": 1}
    data = mapper(request.json)
    return jsonify(data)
```

Comment: Actually I moved on to some other project. Anyway, it is nice to know how you do it. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure. I was kind of expecting that. 
This answer is more in the benefit  of developers who's search lands them to this page :-).

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/dengzhp/simple-jsonrpc

```
import jsonrpc

def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def default(*arg, **kwargs):
    return "hello jsonrpc"

class MyJsonrpcHandler(jsonrpc.JsonrpcHandler):
    """define your own dispatcher here"""
    def dispatch(self, method_name):
        if method_name == "add":
            return add
        else:
            return default


def application(environ, start_response):
    # assert environ["REQUEST_METHOD"] = "POST"
    content_length = int(environ["CONTENT_LENGTH"])

    # create a handler
    h = MyJsonrpcHandler()

    # fetch the request body
    request = environ["wsgi.input"].read(content_length)

    # pass the request body to handle() method
    result = h.handle(request)

    #log
    environ["wsgi.errors"].write("request: '%s' | response: '%s'\n" % (request, result))

    start_response("200 OK", [])
    return [result]
```